# Kivy: other widgets don't work with TreeVIew , widgets don't respond

Tags: python, treeview, kivy

Trying to make an app with treeview and a menu - action bar, they do show there as you can see in the picture but I can't press them, they don't do anything. I tried with BoxLayout, GridLayout and FloatLayout and nothing changed, any idea how to solve it? Thank you!

```
<CloudView>:
name: "cloud"
id: cloud_view
on_pre_enter: root.set_current_user()
tv: tv
actionmenu: actionmenu
my_layout: my_layout
GridLayout:
    id: my_layout
    rows: 3
    TreeView:
        id: tv
    Button:
        text: 'hhh'
        on_release: root.do_something()
    ActionBar:
        id: actionmenu
        pos_hint: {'top':1}
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Action Bar'
                with_previous: False
                on_release: root.do_something()
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn0'
                on_release: root.do_something()
                icon: 'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/audio-volume-high'
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn1'
                on_release: print('Btn1 Pressend')
            ActionButton:
                text: 'Btn2'
            ActionGroup:
                text: 'Group 1'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn3'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn4'
            ActionGroup:
                dropdown_width: 200
                text: 'Group 2'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn5'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn6'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Btn7'
```

[image: how it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionButton` is just an extension of a regular kivy `Button`, so you must assign an `on_release` or `on_press` action as described in the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#kivy.uix.behaviors.button.ButtonBehavior).

Comment: I know, it's not the problem, even if I add on_release or on_press action it still doesn't respond